# Should an account be set up and used solely to install SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, security, configuration, installation, service-accounts

I'd like to follow best practices.
However, is it overkill to create a new service account (with minimal access and no special rights) and then use that account to install SQL Server?

Are there downsides if I do the installation under my administrator account?

Side note: I already have separate service accounts that will run SQL Server engine and SQL Server Agent service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need or benefit to *installing* under a dedicated account as long as you are following other [account-based best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/security-considerations-for-a-sql-server-installation?view=sql-server-ver15).